# What does this assembly code do?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

When I disassembled my C code, I saw the following. What does this code do exactly? Does it have something to do with floating points?

```
movsd  (%rdx,%rax,8),%xmm0
mulsd  %xmm0,%xmm0
movsd  %xmm0,0x30(%rsp)
```

Comment: Well, yes. Didn't searching for `mulsd` tell you what you're after?

Comment: I'more interested in knowing what is xmm0.

Comment: it squares a number: xmm0=*(rdx*8+rax); xmm0*=xmm0; rsp[0x30]=xmmm0;

Comment: @MetallicPriest: google "xmm0" => top link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it squares a number:

```
xmm0=*(rdx*8+rax); 
xmm0*=xmm0; 
rsp[0x30]=xmmm0;
```

xmm0 is a floating point register.